# Architecture advice spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I being asked to do the following :
I have rest end point reactive web service implemented with spring boot, java, and I have a controlled that is authenticated via JWT, the end point is calling service which in tern is calling another 3d party endpoint ( I use webclient to do that) I was asked to take JWT passed to my endpoint , inspect contents and pass this JWT to the 3d party is webLCient header.
Any idea if this will work ?